# Numpy array indexing in C

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a simple way to do simple array indexing of a possibly multi-dimensional numpy array in C?

My use case is very simple.  I have a `PyArrayObject *array`, and I want the value of `array[0]`. If the array is one-dimensional, then I want the item at that index.  If the array is multidimensional, then I want the appropriate slice. (The array won't be zero-dimensional.)

One possibility is to just use the generic facility that any object has for turning `[]` into dictionary lookup:

```
PyObject *zero = PyInt_FromLong(0);
PyObject* result = PyObject_GetItem(array, zero);
```

I note that there is a function (macro?) [`PyArray_GETITEM`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/c-api/array.html), but it seems to only access individual items of the array. And its second argument, `void *itemptr` is not undocumented.

So two questions:

1. Is there something more numpy specific that I can write?
2. What exactly is the second argument to `PyArray_GETITEM`?

---

I figured out the answer to the second question.  The second argument is literally a pointer to an item in the array. So `PyArray_GETITEM(array, PyArray_DATA(array))` will give you the first item of an array, provided it is contiguous.

Still hoping there is a better answer to the first one.

Comment: Yes, the `PyArrayObject` contains the number of dimensions in the array, and a pointer to the first value (`PyArray_DATA`).  From that, you can cast the pointer to the appropriate type and grab however many data members you need.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I'm trying to do.  I literally want a new `PyArrayObject*` that represents exactly the array that I would get by calling `array[0]` in Python.

Comment: Doesn't `PyArray_View` or `PyArray_TakeFrom` do this?  It seems like this would be easier in Python.

Comment: @TimRoberts: `PyArray_View` just lets you view your array as a different element type.  It doesn't do slicing.  `PyArray_TakeFrom` would do what I want, except it seems to make a copy of the data when I try it.

Comment: @TimRoberts: Yeah, this is way much easier in Python. That's why I assumed it would be easy in C, too.  Unfortunately, this is just a middle step in a lot of C code.  I'd really prefer Python.

Comment: In python `x[var]` becomes `x.__getitem__(var)` wbere `var` is an int, list, array, `slice`,and for multidension access a `tuple`..  I think  `*itemptr` must be something like this.